# HtmlAgilityPack Multiple Types of Descendants

Tags: html, linq, html-agility-pack

I am trying to select a divs, spans, labels, etc basically any element with a certain attribute.

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> allDivsWithItemType = _doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("itemtype"));
```

Is there a way to rope all descendants into one like above? Since above only finds divs obviously.  I am trying to avoid duplicate code to add a whole extra line to replace one word.

For Example (Doesn't work)

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> allDivsWithItemType = _doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("*").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("itemtype"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> allDivsWithItemType = _doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
   .Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("itemtype"));
```

Comment: Worked like a charm as far as I can tell.